# django running in virtualenv gives syntax error after executing /usr/share/qgis... (not in virtualenv)

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, qgis

I'm running django using a virtualenv. For some reason, django calls `httplib2` in `/usr/share/qgis/python/httplib2...` where there's a syntax error for some reason.
This never happened before I installed the qgis library from arch's AUR.

I don't understand why is it calling the library that's in qgis? I have this same library in the virtualenv and also on the file system (installed after the error popped-up):

```
[root@arch http]# pacman -Ql | grep httplib2
...
python-httplib2 /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/httplib2/
...
```

This is information abuot my virtualenv:

```
(app)[jenia@arch merging_map_]$ python --version
Python 3.4.1
(app)[jenia@arch merging_map_]$ pip freeze
Django==1.6.5
Pillow==2.5.1
django-simple-captcha==0.4.2
gunicorn==18.0
httplib2==0.9              <-------------- I installed this after finding the error.
ipython==2.1.0
oauthlib==0.6.3
psycopg2==2.5.3
python-social-auth==0.1.26
python3-openid==3.0.4
requests==2.3.0
requests-oauthlib==0.3.1
six==1.7.3
```

Here is the trace back. Its a little long, i think the most interesting is the last lines (the top of the stack). It says that that django tried to use a library in `/usr/share/qgis...`

```
trace back:
Internal Server Error: /login
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/zones/views.py", line 185, in my_login
   user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 47, in authenticate
   for backend in get_backends():
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 22, in get_backends
   backends.append(load_backend(backend_path))
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 16, in load_backend
   return import_by_path(path)()
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
   module = import_module(module_path)
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/google.py", line 7, in <module>
   from social.backends.open_id import OpenIdAuth
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/social/backends/open_id.py", line 1, in <module>
   from openid.consumer.consumer import Consumer, SUCCESS, CANCEL, FAILURE
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openid/consumer/consumer.py", line 194, in <module>
   from openid import fetchers
 File "/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openid/fetchers.py", line 26, in <module>
   import httplib2
 File "/usr/share/qgis/python/httplib2/__init__.py", line 911
   print "connect: (%s, %s) ************" % (self.host, self.port)


   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   /srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site.py:429: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
     fp = open(filename, "rU")
```

So how do I fix it? How do I make python execute the httplib2 that's in the virtualenv?

Thanks in advance for your time and kind help.

Jenia.

---

EDIT 1: system path from the virtualenv:

```
 ['', '/srv/http/merging_map_', 
 '/usr/share/qgis/python',         <----------------------- how did this get here?!!!
 '/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python34.zip', 
 '/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4', 
 '/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', 
 '/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/lib64/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4', 
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-linux', 
 '/srv/http/merging_map_/app/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

How in the world did the qgis folder get into the virtualenv exec paths i dont know. please tell me how to get it out!! and how to replace it with the correct python path.

Comment: What is the output of `python -c "import sys;print sys.path"` with your virtualenv activated?

Comment: you're right Salem. i;m cursed i think. somehow the qgis folder got into the execution path!!

Comment: Maybe it is in PYTHONPATH? Try to deactivate the virtualenv, run `unset PYTHONPATH` and run the previous command again with your venv activated.

Comment: wunderbar!!! thanks very very much salem it worked!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that the problem is that library is in PYTHONPATH. You can remove it just doing

```
$ unset PYTHONPATH
$ source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

Now regarding how it got there: probably you installed something (QGIS) that add it there. You can try to find it where it is defined and remove it

```
$ grep -r "PYTHONPATH" /etc
```

Also you should check in your `.bashrc` and `.profile` files in your home folder. Of course if you remove that entry from python path, the software that needs it may stop working...